# Django admin action for photologue gallery change

Tags: django, photologue

I have a photologue site set up and I really wanted to add an admin action so that when looking at a list of photos in the Django admin I can select a few and mark their respective checkboxes and via an admin action change them to some other gallery. How can something like this be implemented? I already got creating an admin class without having to write the photologue package and adding the action.. but have got no clue on how to send the "gallery" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I got the answer after some more googling in this tutorial here (a bit old but it appears to work) [link](http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/)